# Mandatory page reviewal process

Tags: workflow, publishing

For a publishing site and set of publishing subsites what would be the best way of setting up a page review process.

Each page would have a person responsible (the page owner) who would have to review the page contents every x number of months. The page owner could be determied through a list or property of the document.

To ensure that the review is actually performed correctly the owner would be required to view the page before their task could be completed.

Is this possible to implement in SharePoint and how would I go about it?

Comment: If you are going to -1, leave a comment as to why.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the standard Approval Workflow? It might suffice your needs and you wouldn't need to implement anything. Just activate the feature in your site collection and give it a try (you will need to attach the workflow to your library containing the pages). Also there is the Publishing approval workflow which is basically the same thing just for publishing sites with that you could automatically publish your pages once they are reviewed. In the end your request is the most common request there is for publishing pages ;-)

SharePoint Designer can help you designing your own workflow if you need something more complex, really no need for Visual Studio from what you wrote.